# how can i show/hide a raphael object with button click event

Tags: raphael

## i want to show/hide my raphael svg graph with a button click event

please someone who know how to do this. please help me

i try to do by this way but it's not working.

```
var p = Raphael(900,70,200,200);

p.circle(20,20,20); 
    $n("#shide").click(function(){
    p.hide();
    });
```

please someone who know how to do this. please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd better use the return value of drawing functions.

```
var element1 = p.circle(20,20,20);
var element2 = p.circle(99,99,20);
$n("#shide").click(function(){
    element1.hide();
    // element2.hide();
});
```

Also I have some advanced skills about this kind of problem. These skills will be very usefull when you draw your circles or other things with the ajax response data.

```
function drawCircle() {
    var elementObj = {};
    $.ajax({url: '', dataType: 'json', method: 'post', data: yourData, success: function (data) {
        elementObj['circle1'] = p.circle(20,20,20);
        elementObj['circle2'] = p.circle(99,99,20);
    });
    return elementObj;
}
```

Then you call this function like this:

```
var ele = drawCircle();
var hoverInCb = function () {
    ele['circle1'] && ele['circle1'].show();
    ele['circle2'] && ele['circle2'].show();
};
var hoverOutCb = function () {
    ele['circle1'] && ele['circle1'].hide();
    ele['circle2'] && ele['circle2'].hide();
};
```

These code will work because that the returned elementObj is a 'link' of the object. After the data fetched by ajax request, the elementObj will be filled with data, and the ele variable outside there will also get the new data.

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
var paper = Raphael(10, 50, 320, 200);

paper.circle(10, 10, 10, 10)
     .attr({fill: "#000"})
     .click(function () {
        this.hide();
     });
```

Comment: i want to hide another raphael object not same object on which i click. Suppose there are two circle and i want on click of first circle second one will be hide............. please update the code for this....

Comment: then just create a paper.set (basically it's just an array) and .push circles to it and attach click event to that set. Read docs about .set for example - http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.set